# What is the default password on ubuntu for users created with useradd?

Tags: ubuntu, authorization

In order to install a service on Ubuntu 14.04 like "openemm" I have created a user name and group:

```
sudo sudo useradd openemm -m -G openemm -d /home/openemm
```

Now I want to login with that username

```
su openemm
```

Unfortunatelly the system asks me for a password which I have never set:

```
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Is there a default password? If not, how do I switch to that user in order to start the service

```
su - openemm
openemm.sh start
```

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried pressing enter(no password)?

Comment: Also, you may want to see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/772428/why-does-a-double-sudo-modify-permissions)

Answer (score 7):

There is no default password. You can set a password for your user with

```
sudo passwd openemm
```

It will prompt you for the password twice.

Comment: Also the password won't display anything as it is typed.